# Union-Find/Disjoin-Set data structure for Directed Graph

Tags: graph-algorithm, directed-graph, disjoint-sets

I'm looking for an efficient *Union-Find* (aka [*Disjoint Set*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)) data structure for my [directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph), which has cycles and forests. Given such a graph `G` , I want to to answer following queries:

1. Can I reach node `v` from `u`?
2. From which nodes, `u` is *not* reachable?

For a single "source" node `u`, I can run [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) search and answer whether I can reach `v` from it. A single DFS search will have an upper-bound cost of `m + n` in the worst-case, where `m` and `n` are the number of *vertices* and *edges* in the graph, respectively. However, I have many such "source" nodes and I'm wondering whether there's a better approach than running DFS separately from all `m` "source" nodes (which has an upper-bound cost of `m * (m + n)` in the worst case.)

It seems like both of these questions could be efficiently answered by an Union-Find data-structure for directed graph. To my surprise, I could not find any solution after significant online searches. Am I thinking the problem in wrong direction?

I've found this [answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7360/directed-union-find) but could not comprehend it.